# failed to add DB connection in server explorer visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I work with a friend using SVN. 
I downloaded his solution and tried to add connection to DB via server explorer 
(using mdf file).
He is using SQLExpress and I use SQL SMSS.

my advanced settings are:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\elad\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SVN\UGI\Ugi\Ugi.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```

I got this error. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: see http://techpint.com/programming/error-26-%E2%80%93-error-locating-serverinstance-specified-sql-server or http://forums.asp.net/t/1499314.aspx/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do you have a `Sql Server` instance installed on your machine?

   - You are trying to connect to a local SqlExpress instance. If you want to connect to your friends machine use: `Data Source=[Your friends pc name]\SqlExpress`. `.\SqlExpress` means connect to the instance `SqlExpress` on the local machine.
2. Is the SQL Server instance running?
3. Is the SQL Server setup to allow remote connections?
4. Are TCP/IP and Named Pipes enabled for the SQL Server

I am guessing it's more likely to be point #1 but could be the others as well.

hth